# %02x format specifier for char array

Tags: c, hex, printf, format-specifiers

I have read about %02x format specifiers but when it comes to an argument of type char array, I am unable to understand the output of the following piece of code:

```
int main() {
    // your code goes here
    char str[6] = "abcde";
    char t[3];

    snprintf(t,3,"%02x",str);
    printf("\t%s",t);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
bf
```

How str is being parsed under this format specifier, is a point of concern. What I feel, the output should have been "ab" (without quotes).

Comment: Doesn't your compiler emit any warnings?

Comment: Debugging this and noting the address of `str`, in particular the lowest *byte* of said-address value would probably be rather telling.

Comment: @devnull: no it didn't :(

Comment: @susenj It didn't? [Interesting...](http://ideone.com/rLqbvT)

Comment: you're printing the address of str

Answer (score 2):

The point to make here is that if you are printing anything using %02x then you should be using it for **each** byte. It is common when printing a hash digest to declare a field of size twice the digest size (+1 for \0 if a string) and then populate it with repetitive sprintf() calls.

So one needs to *loop* through the bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [the CPlusPlus entry on printf.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)
I think the format specifier you are looking for is `%2.2s`, which limits the minimum and maximum number of characters printed to 2, and it will print a string, rather than the value of your pointer.

```
main(){
    printf("%2.2s","abcde");
    return 0;
}
```

This will print "ab" (without the quotes). The same format rules apply to the entire printf family, including snprintf.

`%02x` is a format specifier that tells the parser that your value is a number, you want it to be printed in base 16, you want there to be at least 2 characters printed, and that any padding it applies should be full of zeroes, rather than spaces. You need to use some version of `%s` for printing strings.

Answer (score 0):

You should read your source carefully. They might use something like this:

```
int main() {
    char str[6] = "abcde";
    char t[2*6] = { 0 };
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i <= 5; ++i)
    {
        snprintf(t+2*i, sizeof(t)-2*(i), "%02x", str[i]);
    }
    printf("\t%s",t);
    return 0;
}
```

The `%02x` is used to convert one character to a hexadecimal string. Therefore you need to access individual charaters of `str`. You can build a line as my code shows or you can output each converted string as your fragment shows. But then it doesn't make sense to use the temporary variable `t`.

*Edit*: Fixed code.

Comment: Isn't this a SIGSEGV?